# Mantener aspect ratio al cambiar tamaño de ventana

Tags: c++, opengl

El caso es que quiero definir en una función, una matriz de proyección que conserve el aspect ratio de los objetos al cambiar el tamaño de la ventana. La matriz de proyección que tengo que tener en cuenta es la de openGL, que es la siguiente: [image: matriz de proyección openGL]

La función que quiero modificar tiene los siguiente parámetros de entrada:

```
void resizeFunc(int width, int height)
{
    //Ajusta el aspect ratio al tamaño de la ventana
    glm::mat4 proj = glm::mat4(1.0f);
}
```

En la matriz de proyección hay que rellenar los parámetros correspondientes para mantener el aspect ratio. 
En mi caso, yo he calculado el aspect ratio dividiendo width / height y he asignado valores al right, left, top y bottom.

```
void resizeFunc(int width, int height)
{
    //Ajusta el aspect ratio al tamaño de la ventana
    glm::mat4 proj = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    float a_ratio = width / height;
    float near = 1.0f;
    float far = 100.0f;
    float right = a_ratio;
    float left = -a_ratio;
    float top = 1.0f;
    float bottom = -1.0f;
    //Accedemos a la primera fila, primera columna
    proj[0].x = (2 * near) / (right - left); //Apertura horizontal
    //Primera fila, segunda columna
    proj[0].y = 0;
    proj[0].z = (right + left) / (right - left);
    proj[0].w = 0;
    proj[1].x = 0;
    proj[1].y = (2 * near) / (top - bottom); //Apertura vertical
    proj[1].z = (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
    proj[1].w = 0;
    proj[2].x = 0;
    proj[2].y = 0;
    proj[2].z = (-(far + near)) / (far - near);
    proj[2].w = -2 * (far*near) / (far - near);
    proj[3].x = 0;
    proj[3].y = 0;
    proj[3].z = -1;
    proj[3].w = 0;
    IGlib::setProjMat(proj);
}
```

El problema viene en que cuando hago esto, directamente no se ve nada. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float a_ratio = width / height;
```

Dado que `width` y `height` son enteros, el resultado de esa división será un número **entero**, es decir, sin decimales. Después ese entero se convertirá a `float`... pero ya es tarde. Esto limita mucho el alcance del ratio... en cuanto `height` sea mayor que `width` el ratio será siempre 0.

Prueba a forzar la división en `float`:

```
float a_ratio = static_cast<float>(width) / height;.
```